# getting error on Supervison on supervisorctl ERROR (no such process)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, supervisord

I've seen this question asked before, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I'm having problems using the supervisor on my rpi b+. Every time I try to run my start my process, I get an error saying:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo supervisorctl start server
```

> server: ERROR (no such process)

I have my config file set up at /etc/supervisord.conf

```
[program:server]
directory=/home/pi/ledticker
command=/usr/bin/python NetworkServer.py
autostart=false
autorestart=true
stopsignal=QUIT

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10 ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024 ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL for a unix socket

[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock ; (the path to the socket file)
```

I have tried doing the reread, update, reload commands but they haven't worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to accept one of the two proposed answers ?

Comment: For me i didn't see the `process` and also the `supervisorctl reload` didn't work, but after `reboot` it is working..

Answer (score 66):

You should try to reload `supervisord` :

```
# supervisorctl reload
[y/N] ? y
```

In many cases, this error is resolved by that reload.

Answer (score 12):

On my Fedora22, I modified below lines in `/etc/supervisord.conf`:

```
[include]
files = supervisord.d/*.ini
```

to

```
[include]
files = supervisord.d/*.conf
```

and then reload

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'd done wrong. I named my files .conf and didn't realise it only loaded .ini by default :)

Answer (score 8):

i had faced same problem before. It was resolve by following solutions.
First edit your supervisord.conf file and add below lines :

```
[unix_http_server]

file=/tmp/supervisor.sock

chmod=0777
```

- start SupervisorD service first using following command :

  ```
  $ sudo /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
  ```
- You can verify using : ps -ef | grep python
- After supervisord starts, Try to start your program using following command :

  ```
  $ sudo /usr/bin/supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisord.conf start all
  ```

Comment: In my case, I just have to run: `$ sudo /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` and that's all. All good. +1

Answer (score 6):

In case of process multi-instances configuration full process name might look like `server:server_0` (depends on your `process_name` template). Try:

```
sudo supervisorctl restart server:*
```

Otherwise you'll get same (no such process) error.

Answer (score 4):

In some versions of supervisor the **[include]** section not work, you need to add the programs in the main supervisor configuration file in `/etc/supervisord.conf`

Comment: after a couple a whole day, this worked for me!, looks kinda silly, but it did the trick! (CentOS 7)