# Why I get this error laravel-worker: ERROR (no such group)

Tags: laravel, queue, centos7, supervisord

I followed the official Laravel doc to **start queue in the background using supervisor** in *Centos 7*.

**But** whene I run this command `sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*` I get this error `laravel-worker: ERROR (no such group)`

**Documentation**: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: the current version is 5.7, there the queue:work command looks a bit different https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#supervisor-configuration But to your problem: is your file called `laravel-worker.conf`?

Comment: Another error could be caused by that https://stackoverflow.com/a/42574003/1152471

Comment: I use **Laravel 5.5**. Theire are no difference in queue:work command

Comment: Did you test the steps under "Starting Supervisor" in the docs?

Comment: @PKeidel yes I've followed this docs step by step.

Comment: In my case, I had this issue because I created my laravel-worker.conf on the same level with directory 'conf.d'. You have to cd into 'conf.d' to create your worker file

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I tested it out and created a new server with no supervisor configurations at all. These were my steps to get it running:

```
# 1. create the config file, see below for content
vi /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf

# 2. Reload the daemon's configuration files
supervisorctl reread
> laravel-worker: available

# 3. Reload config and add/remove as necessary
supervisorctl update
> laravel-worker: added process group

# 4. Start all processes of the group "laravel-worker"
supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*

# 5. Get status for all processes of the group "laravel-worker"
supervisorctl status laravel-worker:*
> laravel-worker:laravel-worker_00   RUNNING   pid 23758, uptime 0:00:16
> laravel-worker:laravel-worker_01   RUNNING   pid 23759, uptime 0:00:16

# 6. After a change in php sources you have to restart the queue, since queue:work does run as daemon
php artisan queue:restart
> Broadcasting queue restart signal.
```

### /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=2
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/storage/logs/supervisor_queue-work.log
```

Comment: thanks, but in my Centos env i got default config include set to `*.ini` , so I renamed my conf extension  as it is.
`[include]
files = supervisord.d/*.ini`

Comment: Thanks, its solved my issue... Can you please tell how this "user=www-data" user value will come ?

Comment: This just means that the command should be run as another user. You can create a user with minimal access rights and use this user for your queue worker

Comment: @SyamkumarKK "www-data" is the default apache user

Comment: as @bl4cksta mentionned, you should check configuration file extension and location in `/etc/supervisord.conf` (bottom of file).
It was for me `*.ini`
I renamed it to `*.conf`

Comment: for me `apache` instead of `www-data` 
Centos 8

Answer (score 6):

I've the same problem on my cloud based vps. Please check the bottom of supervisord.conf file.

You can find it on

```
nano /etc/supervisord.conf
```

You should carry the `[includes]` section on the configuration file. If the section looks like above.

```
[include]
files = supervisord.d/*.ini
```

change the files parameter extension to **.conf** instead

```
[include]
files = supervisord.d/*.conf
```

otherwise supervisor can not find the laravel-worker configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Put quotes around worker name `sudo supervisorctl start 'laravel-worker:*'`

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the top of your config file is correct. Example:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
```

The below will cause your problem:

```
[program: laravel-worker]
[laravel-worker]
```

Cheers

Comment: my error was also related to the process name.

Your suggestion helped me to identify my error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the process name on config file.
my file was like this

```
[program:omni-delivery-dev-server.config]
...
```

and it stayed like this

```
[program:omni-delivery-dev-server]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have centos8 locate and check supervisor.conf . At the very last you may find

```
[include]
files = supervisord.d/*.ini
```

So don't worry rename `your-file.conf` to `your-file.ini`
and try these commands again

```
supervisorctl reread
```

If you see the change then this is success.

```
supervisorctl update
supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
```

note: if you get some `supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*` message
try adding quote in

```
supervisorctl start 'laravel-worker:*'
```

Answer (score 0):

in new version of supervisor configuration file format is `*.ini` not `*.conf` so rename your file `laravel-worker.conf` to `laravel-worker.ini` and run other commands

```
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl update
supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
```

Answer (score 0):

The supervisor looks for new configuration (`.conf`) files according to the paths defined in the `[include]` section of the `supervisord.conf` file.

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

According to the above snippet, the `supervisorctl` checks for files inside the `conf.d` directory.

There are two actions of choice you can take:

1. Change the directory mentioned in the `supervisord.conf` to the main directory (`/etc/supervisor`) or a directory that you want to put the configuration files.

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/*.conf
```

2. Add the configuration files to the `conf.d` directory.

Either of these actions will work.